# How to make a foreach loop with true and false condition?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, model-view-controller, foreach

> This is my codes. I want to have an output same as this. ['-','e','l','l','o','-','o','o','d','-','o','-','-','-','-','g']

```
        int i = 1;
        List<char> cccc = new List<char>();
        List<char> aaaa = new List<char>(){'H','e','l','l','o','g','o','o','d','m','o','r','n','i','n'};
        List<char> dddd = new List<char>(){'e','l','g','o','d'};

        while (i <=  aaaa.Count()) 
        {
                    foreach(char ch in dddd)
                    {   
                        bool a = aaaa.Any(c => aaaa.Contains(ch));
                        if (aaaa.Contains(ch))
                        {
                            cccc.Add(ch);
                        }
                       else
                        {
                            cccc.Add('-');
                        }
                        i++;
                    }       
        }
        cccc.ForEach(x=>{
            Console.Write(x+" ");
        });
```

> if dddd data is in aaaa then cccc data will remain while if false it will replace by '-'.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @Arphile sort of.

Comment: why do you use while instead of for even you use i as index?

Comment: also you can replace List<char> as String.

Comment: @Arphile even I don't know. never realized it. xD

Comment: @Arphile what about the true and false condition ?

Comment: I am unclear what the question means. You need to explain, in English, how to get from your inputs to your outputs.

Comment: first of all: you should really, really, really, **really** start givig your variables meaningful names - or, at least, any names at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see how one would approach this problem without programming and you would able to solve it by applying similar process in pseudocode:

(1) Examine each character in `aaaa`

(2) If the character exists in `dddd`, keep it as it is

(3) Otherwise, output `-` instead

We can solve (1) by iterating over `aaaa` by using `for`, `foreach` or `while` loop, which was shown in @Arphile's and your solution.

On the other hand, we may solve (2) by using similar approach in (1) as well since we need to iterate over `dddd` to find whether there's a match. Fortunately we can save that effort by using [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1) as shown in @Arphile's answer as well.

Lastly, the conditional can be achieved using [`if-else`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) or an elvis / conditional operator [`?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Combining all of these along with LINQ, we will have something like this:

```cs
char[] charList = new [] { 'H','e','l','l','o','g','o','o','d','m','o','r','n','i','n','g' };
char[] allowedChars = new [] { 'e','l','g','o','d' };

IEnumerable<char> filteredChars = charList.Select(c => allowedChars.Contains(c) ? c : '-');

// Output : -,e,l,l,o,g,o,o,d,-,o,-,-,-,-,g
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", filteredChars));
```

Side note: You may append [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netcore-3.1) if would like to keep the filtered characters in an array instead.

Comment: How can I aply this "IEnumerable<char> filteredChars = charList.Select(c => allowedChars.Contains(c) ? c : '-') " into this transaction_details txn in transactions ? where  transactions  has debit value that I will insert into another list.

Comment: I afraid you'll need to create another question to address the issue you're facing since it's out of the scope based on the question you asked earlier. Kindly check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266140/should-i-edit-my-question-or-create-a-new-one) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<char> output = new List<char>();
List<char> input = new List<char>() { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'i', 'n' };
List<char> compare = new List<char>() { 'e', 'l', 'g', 'o', 'd' };

foreach(char curr in input)
{
    bool isCurrInCompare = compare.Any(x => x.Equals(curr));
    if (isCurrInCompare)
        output.Add(curr);
    else
        output.Add('-');
}
output.ForEach(x => Console.Write(x + " "));
```

Answer (score -1):

Because I think it's part of homework, I'll not give you a perfect solution.

but, I think this code will lead you to solution.

```
    List<char> aaaa = new List<char>(){'H','e','l','l','o','g','o','o','d','m','o','r','n','i','n'};
    List<char> dddd = new List<char>(){'e','l','g','o','d'};

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < aaaa.Count; i++ ) {
        if ( !dddd.Contains(aaaa[i])) { // if a char is not contained in dddd
            Console.Write('-');
        }
        else { // if a char is contained in dddd
            Console.Write(aaaa[i]);
        }
    }
```

This code will print as replaced if dddd contains aaaa's char.

output is '-ellogood-o----'

hope this code will help you.

Comment: i added my real codes

Answer (score -1):

```
                List<decimal> money= new List<decimal>();
                int k = 1;
                while (k <= arrayresult.Count())
                {
                    foreach (transaction_details txn in transactions)
                    {
                        if (arrayresult.Contains(txn .Transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")))
                        {
                            var a = txn .Transdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            money.Add(txn .Debit);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var b = "";
                            money.Add(0);
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
               
                }

// arrayresult is a list of dates.
```

Comment: @Arphile this is my real codes. cant apply urs.

Comment: definitely I cannot understand what exact question is. not clear what do you want to do.